# Access data by MQTT client sequently

Tags: python, mqtt

I am a junior Python programmer. I want to implement a MQTT client for continuously receiving and processing messages:

```
records = []
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
   payload = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
   records.append(payload)
```

...

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("XX.XX.XX.XX", XXXX, XX)
client.loop_forever()
#  for r in records:
    #  do something with r
```

When the client begins to receive payload, data will be stored in a list ***records***. Another function will （asynchronously or not, either is Ok） access these data according to the sequence that they enter the list ***records***. I have no idea how to realize it, or when a message is received, it will be processed by a function. when the next message is coming, the function will continue to process it and so on.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried to add the function call after each message is received in method on_message. But the processing time is too long, no desired results are obtained , before the next message comes.

Comment: Stack Overflow won't write this for you, you have to at least try and then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: can you post the codes you have tried already ?